# Как вызывать функцию не передавая параметры если она содержит параметр со значением

Tags: sql, sql-server, функции

```
CREATE FUNCTION funk (@percent INT=22)
RETURNS int
BEGIN
return @percent
END
```

я попробовал select dbo.funk() но не получается

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если параметр функции имеет значение по умолчанию, то для него должно быть указано ключевое слово DEFAULT для получения функцией значения по умолчанию.

```
select dbo.funk(default)
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql